# Connect to Azure Database for Postgresql through VPN

Tags: azure, networking, azure-sql-database, vpn

While configuring an Azure managed Postgres service, I am trying to configure connecting from local machines through VPN.

I can connect to the DB when white-listing IPs in Connection Security.
I have added the subnet the VPN-gateway is connected to to the *VNET Rules* – this doesn't seem to make a difference.

I *can* connect to VMs through the VPN from my local machine. 
However to make that work, I added the VMs' (private IP, Azure URL)-pairs to my local machines `hosts`-file.

I can't find any IP for the DB-service (which seems to make sense for a managed service), so I can't make the same trick.
The error I'm getting, when trying to connect to the DB, is similar to the ones I got before adding `hosts` mappings.

This all leads me to believe I need some way of having Azure resolve the URL (which might also preempt the need for `hosts`-mappings in general).

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#azure-provided-name-resolution), I tried setting my DNS for 168.63.129.16, but that doesn't work at all (nothing at all is resolved).

Is there a way (and if so, how) to connect from a local machine to an Azure Database for Postgresql service through a VPN gateway?

Comment: I clarified the phrasing slightly. I'll comment directly on your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this as your desired. You want to map an Azure database logical server private IP to your local `hosts` file, then access it via VPN gateway.

You only know the public IP for the Azure database server. The public IP addresses of Azure services change periodically. You could find [an IP address list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=41653) by filtering your region. It does not recommend to use such a dynamic IP address. Refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2014/03/27/dont-rely-on-a-static-ip-address-for-your-sql-database/).

Since Azure database is a fully managed Platform as a Service (PaaS) Database Engine not IaaS like Azure virtual machines, It's public and does not expose the database server private IP address. We only could access the database via Azure database server name over the Internet.

Furthermore, if you want to restrict its access only from a private network with [virtual Network service endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-data-access-and-security-vnet). However, this works to allow resources like Azure VM in the authorized subnet to access directly your Azure database in a private network, could not guarantee that if you could access the Azure database from your local machine via VPN. This seems no on-premise route to your Azure database.

Comment: As you say, the first method would only give me the public IP. 
I don't think this would work, as the traffic would still be routed over the internet – not directly in the vnet – so I don't see how this could work.
Your link seems more or less related to what I'm trying to do, but I don't understand the contents sufficuently to conclude whether it means that there is no way of making the connection with our current setup.

Comment: Yes, I mean no way to do this as your desired. If you really want to know an IP for database, you only know the public IP, which is not working in a private network.

Comment: Upvoted for being helpful. However, it seems inconclusive, so I am leaving the question open.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-database-services-for-mysql-and-postgresql-in-preview/) `VNet service endpoints don’t extend to on-premises. To allow access from on-premises, firewall rules can be used to limit connectivity only to your public (NAT) IPs.` so it's impossible to access the database via on-premise private IP unless the database is inside a VNet.

Comment: Is this still the case? I have my postgress on a private DNS zone. Would like to be able to access it from my local environment